# Форматирование строки без использования регулярных выражений

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой список строк:

```
['2nd July 1961',
 '6th August 1962',
 '31st July 1965']
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать `nd`, `th` и `st` у чисел без использования регулярных выражений?
Спасибо

Comment: а почему без `"без использования регулярных выражений"` ? Код будет не очень красиво выглядеть...

Comment: Ну что-то типа использования цикла. Методов isdigit(), isalpha(). Если можно напишите, пожалуйста, и так и так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант:

```
_list = [
    '2nd July 1961',
    '6th August 1962',
    '31st July 1965'
]

def my_func(_list):
    new_list = []
    for _d in _list:
        for i in ('nd', 'st', 'th'):
            ind = _d.find(i)
            if ind == -1 or ind > 2:
                continue
            else:
                new_list.append(_d[:ind]+_d[ind+2:])
    return new_list

print(my_func(_list))

#['2 July 1961', '6 August 1962', '31 July 1965']
```

Comment: Спасибо. Тоже вариант хороший

Answer (score 1):

```
def cut_date_suffix(input_str):
    i = 0
    while i < len(input_str) - 1:
        i += 1
        if input_str[i - 1].isdigit() and input_str[i:i+2] in ('nd', 'st', 'th'):
            break
    return input_str[:i] + input_str[i + 2:]
```

Comment: Спасибо. А что если переделать функцию, чтобы она принимала лист дат, и возвращала лист форматируемых дат?

Comment: Для этого можно воспользоваться генератором списка с предложенной функцией.

Answer (score 0):

```
def change_data(dates_list: list):
    formated_dates = []
    for item in dates_list:
        if not item[1].isdigit():
            item = item[0] + item[3:]
        else:
            item = item[:2] + item[4:]
        formated_dates.append(item)
    return formated_dates
```

Comment: Там был комментарий о срезах. Получился такой вариант. Вроде работает